# Error on upload imagem with php and mysqli

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a image to my database with PHP, I've checked multiple aspects and nothing works and I don't know what is wrong. I generate a string to give a random to the image and I've check and `$target_file = "../uploads/dsfjnsklsdlkfmsd.png"`.

From the `print_r($_FILES);` below I get the following:

```
Array ( [imagem_capa] => Array ( [name] => filexpto.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php25C3.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 11229 ) )
```

I'll leave my code here:

```
<?php

include_once "../connection/connection.php";

//random string
function generateRandomString($length = 10)
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

//connection
$link = new_db_connection();
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

//upload image
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["imagem_capa"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$file_name = generateRandomString() . "." . $imageFileType;
$target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["imagem_capa"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Desculpa, essa imagem já existe.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    return;
}

if ($_FILES["imagem_capa"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "A imagem é demasiado grande";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    return;
}

if (
    $imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif"
) {
    echo "Carrega uma imagem jpg, jpeg, png ou gif, por favor.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    return;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    header("Location: ../main.php?erro=2");
} else {        
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagem_capa"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        //does insert

    } else {
        print_r($_FILES);
    }
}
```

On the statement of `move_uploaded_file()` goes to the else.

Comment: Always check `$_FILES["imagem_capa"]["error"]` before doing anything

Comment: I don't see anything being added to the database. You init the statement, but never do anything with it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly returns 0

Comment: I do, I just didn't paste it here because the error is on move_uploaded_file() statement @aynber

Comment: So does `../uploads/` folder exist, and if so can you tell us the full path to it

Comment: Try to avoid relative paths like`../uploads/`, you may be moving the image to the wrong directory, use always absolute paths. Also check that the folder you are moving the image exists, and the user under php is runing has write access to the folder.

Comment: I did the entire path and still not working

Comment: print_r($_FILES["imagem_capa"]["error"]); returns 0 but if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagem_capa"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) goes to else @DavidRojo

Comment: This is $target_file -> http://url/images/uploads/wtg6jG7rGc.pn